# Implementing a Chebyshev filter in python

Tags: python, r, scipy, filtering, smoothing

I am trying to run a chebyshev filter on my data in python. I specifically want to get rid of higher frequencies.

I first run a 3 day high pass filter on my data. To do this, I use the following function

```py
from scipy import signal

sos = signal.cheby1(0, 1,(1/(3*24)),'hp',fs=1/24,output='sos'
chev_3day_10 =signal.sosfilt(sos,u_rot)
```

u_rot is the hourly data I am trying to filter.

I am comparing this to a 7-hour filter.

```py
from scipy import signal

sos = signal.cheby1(0, 1,(1/((7/24)*24)),'low',fs=1/24,output='sos')
```

In this function, 0 is the order of the filter, 1 is the maximum ripple allowed. fs is the sampling frequency of the system. For my case, its an 1 hour/day.

For reference, this code in R is what I am trying to recreate.

```r
chev_3day_10m=pass.filt(u.rot,W=(1/((7/24)*24)),type="low",method = "ChebyshevI")
```

The 3 day filter is giving me a reasonable results (from what I'm aiming to reproduce). However, the 7 hour filter is only decreasing the amplitude of the resulting curve. There is no further smoothing of the data.

I have tried adjusting the order and the maximum ripple, but it still only seems to be changing the magnitude. Does anyone have experience using chebyshev filters in python?

FYI, I am new at using stack overflow, if there any formatting issues or big "no no's" please comment.

Comment: About the R code: I think this is a 7 day filter, rather than a 7 hour filter. `(1/(1/7)*24)` is equal to 168 in R, because multiplications and division have equal precedence.

Comment: In your first example, the filter is saved to the variable `sos`, but the filter you're using is `sos_7hour`. Is this a typo?

Comment: @NickODell Thanks. I rewrote it wrong. It should be updated